# Navbar Dropdown in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started learning and using Bootstrap 3. I figured I would start with something simple- a header and a dropdown bar. I used the code from the Bootstrap website.

I started out with the basic Bootstrap template, then added the bootstrap navbar. This is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WEBSITE NAME</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>WEBSITE NAME</h1>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://youtube.com/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The dropdown menu is absolutely not working at all- hovering or clicking it. What do I need to do?

**EDIT:** I used the Safari web inspector and the resource "jquery.js" is red (indicating it is missing). This comes from the lines:
        
        
        
        
I am writing this based off the default basic page from the Bootstrap site. **I'm not sure what to change the path to in order to correct it.** There is no 'jquery.js' file in the project folder provided.

Comment: There are a lot of changes between Bootstrap and Bootstrap 3(.2.3). Always check if the classes are included in your css-file. Not sure if this is the case right now, but it might be worth checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Success!**

I noticed that the 'code.jquery.com/jquery.js' file was unreachable in the Safari web inspector. The issue was this line:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

The file could not be reached. For some reason, the http: part was missing. Changing the code to

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

fixed the issue! Huzzah!

Additional Note: It think that, if this were run online and not locally, the http: part would not be required.

Comment: As you say, the 'http:' is not "missing" - this is what's called a 'protocol-independent' reference. It's used to ensure that if you are currently on an http page the asset will be loaded over http and if you are on an https page it will be loaded over https (therefore avoiding mixed content warnings). As you were viewing the page on a 'file:///' url then this will have caused you problems...

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code after taking out the "html5shiv" and "respond.min" references and the dropdown menu works fine.  I suspect the jQuery and Bootstrap JS files may have their file paths stated incorrectly.

Comment: Which section are you specifically referring to?

Comment: @user2333842 The very bottom "src" references.  Are they pointing to the correct paths?

Answer (score 0):

the section:-

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Twitter</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://youtube.com/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> YouTube</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

has an extra </ul> and </li> - which is probably not causing your problem, but won't be helping...

Answer (score 0):

I loaded this exact file onto my WAMP server locally and everything worked perfectly fine:
You might want to change this at the bottom of the page:
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"
There is nothing wrong with your code and the HTML5 shiv and respond.js has nothing to do with your menu not working...

You might however want to use Google Chrome and use the inspect element to make sure your reference points are correct.

Hover doesn't work out of the box in BS3, you can use a custom javascript to get that working... I use it here: http://thisamericanjourney.com/
hover over the about menu item:
       //This allows the user to hover over the menu without clicking on it

```
   $(function() {


$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut('fast');
});

    });
```

Comment: I have all the files on my computer (locally). I have everything in the 'dist' folder. There are the three folders, css, fonts, and js, and my 'index.html' file.                                                               For what it's worth, I use the Safari web browser.

Comment: What do you recommend I do the line '<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>' ?

Comment: Yes EXACTLY :-) That is what I was trying to tell you,... Glad to see you got it working! I tried to tell you in my post here:            You might want to change this at the bottom of the page: src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" with an absolute path to jQuery :-)

Comment: Folks, im having almost the same issue!  dropdown does not work on latest Chrome, but Safari it works :(